# 2003 honda accord battery light

Tags: honda, battery, accord, power-steering

Battery light keeps coming on and off and power steering feels like it is going out. New battery a year ago, new alternator a year ago. Replaced the accessory belt a week ago as well as the accessory belt tensioner. Light still comes off and on and power steering feels like it is going out once in a while after.

Comment: Have someone turn the steering wheel back and forth while you watch the belt. It sounds like the belt might be slipping.

Comment: Do both symptoms happen at the same time all the time?

Comment: I would like to add that it possibly could be the bearing in the alternator. I know you said it was new a year ago, but it is very possible that there was a defect in the bearing which led to a very short life. The bearing being bad could cause the belt to slip and thus you'd notice the power steering getting weaker.

Comment: Hi @Dianna - did you get a resolution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Bring the vehicle to a Retail Automotive Parts store which offers a free battery and charging system test, or use a multi-meter to rule out whether or not you are getting clean voltage from the alternator.

It sounds like either there is an issue with conductivity, or the alternator is not functioning properly, or there is excessive belt deflection and/or a frozen pulley.

Assure your battery terminals are clean and tight. Assure that your grounds are clean and tight. Inspect wiring for signs of damage.

A frozen pulley would likely make a horrible noise. A loose belt would likely make a horrible noise under heavy throttle. Just generalizing here.

Answer (score 0):

Power steering bearing would stick or hang or lock up .you should be able to hear belt if slipping . light comes on off sounds like voltage regulator in alternator getting week or ground getting week to light it's self .I would think voltage regulator is getting bad .not bad enough not to charge yet just not keeping steady current.ive been there done that. Hope you have good luck and find it that's aggravating